# Как изменять переменную в скрипте другого игрока Photon Unity?

Tags: c#, unity3d

У каждого игрока есть переменная (условно назовем ее очки).

Так вот, я пытаюсь из одного скрипта игрока, изменить эту переменную у другого игрока, но никак не выходит.

Что я пробовал :

[PunRPC]

photonView.RPC("метод", RpcTarget.Others);

На англоязычных я тоже особо ничего не нашел, там оригиналы тех статей/вопросов переводы которых я находил ранее, а в оф. Документации Photon'a я не пойму куда копать, описанные ранее методы тоже там искал и пытался реализовать по документации - эффект тот же